# Chrome Extension Notification Not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I can't tell what's wrong with this code:

In my listener on background.js I have the following

```
    if (request=="notify") {
        chrome.notifications.create({title: "Title", message: "There is an time slot available", iconUrl: "icon.png",type: "basic"});;
    }
```

and in my content_script.js I call it using this:

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("notify");
```

Notifications are enabled, but nothing is popping up. In my manifest.json I have

```
"permissions": [ "notifications", "tabs", "activeTab", "background" ],
```

Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the surrounding code in your background.js executes at all? Are you listening for messages using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(json, sender){})` ?

Comment: Yes - everything else runs. Another listener correctly interprets the message it receives.  Here's the first line of the listener: chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)

Answer (score 1):

The following code in `background.js`

```
chrome.notifications.create({title: "Title", message: "There is an time slot available", iconUrl: "icon.png", type: "basic"})
```

with the following manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Hello!",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "notifications", "tabs", "activeTab", "background"
    ],
    
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

produces the expected result:
[image]

Therefore I assume your issue to be either:

1. The image path is not valid (the notification will not show otherwise).
   You can check the console for your background script from the Extensions page:
   [image]
2. You have at some point disabled notifications for the browser (e.g. in Settings ➜ Notifications & actions on Windows) and forgot about that.